# Primefaces fixed height data table with lazy loading of data

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I used datatable of primefaces 2 but I notice that when I set the scrollable property to true
and the loading is set to lazy, the table layout in both Firefox and Chrome is not rendering fine.

I wanted to set a fixed height on the table and still enable lazy loading of data.

```
<p:dataTable var="trike" value="#{myBean.carModel}" rows="10"
                                 paginator="true" lazy="true" paginatorPosition="bottom" scrollable="true" height="150">
```

Is this not possible?

Comment: Strange problem... try setting the `styleClass` property to a css class that will give the table a fixed height.  See if that works.

Comment: Hi, Have you experienced this?